# CSS Word-wrap is cutting words in half

Tags: css, html

I have a div element set up

```
<div id="foo" class="bar"></div>
```

where bar

```
bar{word-wrap:break-word;white-space:normal;overflow-x:no-scroll;overflow-y:scroll;POSITION:static;display:inline-block;text-align:left;}
```

However several words are being cut in half at the end of the area.

I've tried setting the word-wrap property to normal, initial and inherit with no success.

Am i misunderstanding the functionality of word wrap?

[image: Words are not wrapped?]

**EDIT**

by using break-word i get this

[image]

**EDIT**
This is the whole css for bar.

```
.bar{BORDER:1px solid;height:<%=nHeight%>px;width:<%=nWidth/2%>px;max-width:<%=nWidth/2%>px; word-wrap:break-word;white-space:normal;overflow-x:no-scroll;overflow-y:scroll;POSITION:static;background-color:#FFFFFF;cursor:default;display:inline-block;margin-top:6px;text-align:left;}
```

**EDIT**

Seems i run css 2.1

Comment: how about using word-break property? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp

Comment: @Rjonacci It cuts words still :/

Comment: I think the real issue is that your CSS selector is wrong. You select `bar {...}` which should be `.bar {...}`. I've also never heard of the value `no-scroll` for any overflow setting.

Comment: @doge http://jsbin.com/danuv/2/edit

Comment: @JustusRomijn Thanks for helping, is it worth mentioning that this site is IE-ONLY due to heavy vbscript usage?

Comment: IE does not have other behaviour than other browsers on this part.

Comment: But I do notice usage of `inline-block`, which is known to have buggy behaviour on IE rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are mixing stuff up. If you want words not to break, only when a word is really long and does not fit on a line, you only have to use `word-wrap: break-word`.

HTML:

```
<div id="foo" class="bar"></div>
```

CSS: (relevant values only)

```
.bar {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/c2JPz/2/

So what you should do is change:

`overflow-x:` <del>no-scroll</del> `hidden`

`display:` <del>inline-block</del> `block` (or remove this rule because this is default styling for a `div`)